# how to add a new object using mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I would like to add for each iteration a new item on the timeEntries object inside the Student schema.
I have tried different ways but didn have success with it.

My student schema as below:

```
var StudentSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
        //validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: ''
        //validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
    },
    worksnap: {
        user: {
            type: Object
        },
        timeEntries: {
            type: Object
        },
    }
});
```

And here is the code where I am trying to add new objects into timeEntries:

```
_.forEach(timeEntries, function (timeEntry) {
                _.forEach(timeEntry, function (item) {
                    Student.findOne({'worksnap.user.user_id': item.user_id[0]})
                        .populate('user')
                        .exec(function (err, student) {
                            if (err) {
                                throw err;
                            }  
                            student.worksnap.timeEntries = item;
                            student.save(function (err) {
                                if (err) {
                                    //return res.status(400).send({
                                    //    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                                    //});
                                } else {
                                    //res.json(student);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                });
            });
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It seems there is no `Object` type in mongoose [schema type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html), maybe you could use `Mixed` type for `timeEntries`

Comment: Or you could replace `findOne` with `update` operation as below 'Student.update({'worksnap.user.user_id': item.user_id[0]}, {$set: {'student.worksnap.timeEntries': item}}, function(err, stu){})'?

Comment: @zangw I tried your way, it is not working either...its not even adding one...my previous solution was adding one object for each user, but instead should add more than that, whenever there is a match

Comment: Sorry for some mistakes for previous comment, `Student.update({'worksnap.user.user_id': item.user_id[0]}, {$set: {'worksnap.timeEntries': item}}, function(err, stu){})`? BTW, is there one field `user_id` nested in the `user`? if so, you should define it clearly in the `user` schema

Comment: @zangw, it adds only one item for a student, instead should push item each time there is a match, and I am sure there is a match for each of the users like more than one... seems a bit closer to the solution... thnx anyhow.. btw yes, I do have user_id attribute nested within user object.

Comment: `push item each time there is a match` mean you want to push item to `worksnap.timeEntries`? Sorry, I cannot catch you...

Comment: exactly, I want to push a new item into worksnap.timeEntries whenever the condition '{'worksnap.user.user_id': item.user_id[0]' is met within each iteration...

Comment: for ex: I have like 4-6 items that have the same item.user_id with worksnap.user.user_id, and it is adding only once, seems adding only the last one into timeEntries, instead I would want 4-6 items to be added into timeEntries....

Comment: You should change your schema as array type like `timeEntries:[ {/*detail of fields*/}],`, please read more details from this http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Comment: Then to push elements into `timeEntries` like ` student.worksnap.timeEntries.push(item);`

Comment: I have changed to this: timeEntries: [{
            type:Object
        }], still not working :s

Comment: Could you please update your codes in your question? Also as I mentioned before, there is no `Object` type in mongoose schema type.